# How can i display a previous range in ShadCN calendar/

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-day-picker

I want to dynamically display a second range based on a checkbox in the Calendar.
How can i pass the second range and give it a different color?

```
"use client";

import {
  format,
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  startOfWeek,
  endOfWeek,
  startOfMonth,
  endOfMonth,
  subDays,
  sub,
} from "date-fns";

import { Calendar as CalendarIcon } from "lucide-react";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Calendar } from "@/components/ui/calendar";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import { RadioGroup, RadioGroupItem } from "@/components/ui/radio-group";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DateRange } from "react-day-picker";

interface DatePickerProps {
  value:
    | DateRange
    | {
        from: string;
        to: string;
      };
  setValue: (
    val:
      | DateRange
      | {
          from: string;
          to: string;
        }
  ) => void;
  compareValue: string;
  setCompareValue: (val: string) => void;
  enableCompare: boolean;
  setEnableCompare: (val: boolean) => void;
}

const DatePicker: React.FC<DatePickerProps> = ({
  value,
  setValue,
  compareValue,
  setCompareValue,
  enableCompare,
  setEnableCompare,
}) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState<undefined | DateRange>();
  const [prevPeriodRange, setPrevPeriodRange] = useState<
    DateRange | undefined
  >();
  const today = new Date();
  const getSelectedDateRange = (radioOption: string): DateRange | undefined => {
    switch (radioOption) {
      case "today":
        return { from: startOfDay(today), to: endOfDay(today) };
      case "week":
        return { from: startOfWeek(today), to: endOfWeek(today) };
      case "month":
        return { from: startOfMonth(today), to: endOfMonth(today) };
      default:
        return undefined;
    }
  };
  const handleRadioChange = (value: string) => {
    const newDate = getSelectedDateRange(value);
    setDate(() => newDate);
  };
  const handleValueChange = useCallback(
    (newValue: { from: string; to: string }) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    },
    [setValue]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("DATE PICKER DATE", date);
    if (date && date !== undefined && "from" in date) {
      const formattedDate: {
        from: string;
        to: string;
      } = {
        from: date.from ? format(date.from, "yyyy-MM-dd") : "",
        to: date.to ? format(date.to, "yyyy-MM-dd") : "",
      };
      console.log("formatted date", formattedDate);
      handleValueChange(formattedDate);
    }
  }, [date, handleValueChange]);

  const renderComparisonRange = () => {
    if (enableCompare && date?.from !== undefined && date?.to !== undefined) {
      const [from, to] = [new Date(date.from), new Date(date.to)];

      switch (compareValue) {
        case "1": // Previous Period
          // Calculate the duration between 'from' and 'to'
          const durationInDays = Math.ceil(
            (to.getTime() - from.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
          );

          // Calculate the 'previousFrom' and 'previousTo' based on the duration
          //   const previousFrom = sub(from, { days: durationInDays });
          //   const previousTo = sub(to, { days: durationInDays });
          const lastMonthFrom = sub(from, { days: 31 });
          const lastMonthTo = sub(to, { days: 31 });

          setPrevPeriodRange({
            from: lastMonthFrom,
            to: lastMonthTo,
          });
          break;
        case "2": // Same Period, Last Year
          const lastYearFrom = sub(from, { days: 365 });
          const lastYearTo = sub(to, { days: 365 });
          setPrevPeriodRange({
            from: lastYearFrom,
            to: lastYearTo,
          });
          break;
        default:
          setPrevPeriodRange(undefined);
      }
    }
  };
  const handleSelectChange = (value: string) => {
    renderComparisonRange();
    setCompareValue(value);
  };
  return (
    <Popover>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant={"outline"}
          className={cn(
            "w-[280px] justify-start text-left font-normal",
            !date && "text-muted-foreground"
          )}
        >
          <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
          <span>Date Range</span>
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0">
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="p-5">
            <RadioGroup
              defaultValue="custom"
              onValueChange={(value) => handleRadioChange(value)}
            >
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <RadioGroupItem value="today" id="option-one" />
                <Label htmlFor="option-one">Today</Label>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <RadioGroupItem value="week" id="option-two" />
                <Label htmlFor="option-two">This Week</Label>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <RadioGroupItem value="month" id="option-three" />
                <Label htmlFor="option-three">This Month</Label>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <RadioGroupItem value="custom" id="option-four" />
                <Label htmlFor="option-four">Custom</Label>
              </div>
            </RadioGroup>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Calendar
              mode="range"
              //   selected={enableCompare ? renderComparisonRange() : date}
              selected={date}
              onSelect={setDate}
              initialFocus
              showOutsideDays={false}
              numberOfMonths={2}
            />
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 text-xs">
              <label htmlFor="comparisonCheckbox">Compare To</label>
              <Checkbox
                id="comparisonCheckbox"
                checked={enableCompare}
                onCheckedChange={() => setEnableCompare(!enableCompare)}
              ></Checkbox>

              <div>
                <Select
                  value={compareValue}
                  onValueChange={handleSelectChange}
                  disabled={!enableCompare}
                >
                  <SelectTrigger className="w-auto">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    <SelectGroup>
                      <SelectItem defaultChecked value="1">
                        Previous Period
                      </SelectItem>
                      <SelectItem value="2">Same Period, Last Year</SelectItem>
                    </SelectGroup>
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                {date && enableCompare && (
                  <span className="border-solid border-2 border-gray-300">
                    {prevPeriodRange && (
                      <span>
                        {format(prevPeriodRange.from as Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")} -{" "}
                        {format(prevPeriodRange.to as Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")}
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </span>
                )}
                {date && (
                  <span className="border-solid border-2 border-gray-300">
                    {format(date.from as Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")} -{" "}
                    {date.to ? format(date.to as Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") : ""}
                  </span>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
};

export default DatePicker;
```

i initally tried modifying the selected props but thats too ugly and causestypescript to act up, the example in the react-day-picker docs shows a custom array of dates being passed but i want to pass a date range and i cant figure out how.